# Magento - System Config menu option empty after adding customized payment method

Tags: magento

I see all drop down options are gone from my System/Configuration items after I have added my customized payment method, even I removed this new payment method. Any idea what's wrong and how to recover it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. It belongs on the Stack Overflow's sister-site https://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Inspects the elements by the browser, stopped showing it must have given any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to clear the cache completely (empty magento/var/cache/ folder if needed) and/or log out and back in again for all changes to take effect in the backend.